# Formatting for Appendix only

Tags: sectioning, packages, appendices, thesis

I was wondering if there is an easy way to style and format the appendix different from the thesis. Precisely, I use less width and larger font-size for thesis. The appendix mostly contains proofs and hence, I want wider width and small font-size. I want them attached as one pdf and not distinct pdfs. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can use the `\newgeometry` command from `geometry` to change margins.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I think it solves my problem. If you can add it as an answer I will be happy to accept. Is there no easy way to change the styling for a specific part of the document?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by ‘styling’. B.t.w., \newgeometry starts a new page.

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of that. Geometry takes care of font size as well. I suppose

Comment: I don't think. But you can just write, say, `\appendix \small`, unless you want specific font sizes.

Comment: @Bernard That worked thanks!!